# How do I process PHP in batches?

Tags: php, xml

I using PHP to connect a MySQL DB and a 3rd party API. When using the following script I keep getting a timeout error. The owners of the API I'm using suggest limiting each call to 50 records. I'm new to PHP and despite all my Googling can't work out how to batch process. The script is as follows:

```
<?php

include('config.inc.php');


$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $passwd, $db);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  echo 'Database connection failed...' . 'Error: ' . $conn->connect_errno . ' ' . $conn->connect_error;
  exit;
} else {
  $conn->set_charset('utf8');
}

$sql = "SELECT Duedate, Invoicenumber, customername, txndate, itemref_fullname, xeroaccountnumber, Description, Quantity, rate, XEROTAXTYPE FROM invoicelinedetail";

$rs = $conn->query($sql);

if ($rs == false) {

} else {

  require('xeroconfig.php');

  $XeroOAuth = new XeroOAuth(array_merge(array(
    'application_type' => XRO_APP_TYPE,
    'oauth_callback' => OAUTH_CALLBACK,
    'user_agent' => $useragent
  ), $signatures));


  $initialCheck = $XeroOAuth->diagnostics();
  $checkErrors = count($initialCheck);
  if ($checkErrors > 0) {
    // you could handle any config errors here, or keep on truckin if you like to live dangerously
    foreach ($initialCheck as $check) {
      echo 'Error: ' . $check . PHP_EOL;
    }
  } else {
    $session = persistSession(array(
        'oauth_token' => $XeroOAuth->config ['consumer_key'],
        'oauth_token_secret' => $XeroOAuth->config ['shared_secret'],
        'oauth_session_handle' => ''
    ));
    $oauthSession = retrieveSession();

    if (isset($oauthSession ['oauth_token'])) {
      $XeroOAuth->config ['access_token'] = $oauthSession ['oauth_token'];
      $XeroOAuth->config ['access_token_secret'] = $oauthSession ['oauth_token_secret'];

      $xml = "<Invoices>\n";

      foreach ($rs as $row) {
        $xml .= "<Invoice>\n";
        $xml .= "<Type>ACCREC</Type>\n";
        $xml .= "<Contact>\n";
        $xml .= "<Name>" . xmlEscape($row['customername']) . "</Name>\n";
        $xml .= "</Contact>\n";
        $xml .= "<Date>" . xmlEscape($row['txndate']) . "</Date>\n";
        $xml .= "<DueDate>" . xmlEscape($row['Duedate']) . "</DueDate>\n";
        $xml .= "</Invoice>\n";
      }

      $xml .= "</Invoices>";
      #echo $xml;

      $response = $XeroOAuth->request('POST', $XeroOAuth->url('Invoices', 'core'), array(), $xml);

      if ($XeroOAuth->response['code'] == 200) {
        $invoice = $XeroOAuth->parseResponse($XeroOAuth->response['response'], $XeroOAuth->response['format']);
        echo "" . count($invoice->invoices[0]) . " invoice created/updated in this Xero organisation.";
        if (count($invoice->Invoices[0]) > 0) {
          echo "The first one is: </br>";
          pr($Invoice->Invoices[0]->Invoice);
        }
      } else {
        outputError($XeroOAuth);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You case use the % operator to make a request every 50 invoices. Something like this (you may have to change count($rs) to something else depending on what type of object it is).

```
<?php

include('config.inc.php');    

$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $passwd, $db);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  echo 'Database connection failed...' . 'Error: ' . $conn->connect_errno . ' ' . $conn->connect_error;
  exit;
} else {
  $conn->set_charset('utf8');
}

$sql = "SELECT Duedate, Invoicenumber, customername, txndate, itemref_fullname, xeroaccountnumber, Description, Quantity, rate, XEROTAXTYPE FROM invoicelinedetail";

$rs = $conn->query($sql);

if ($rs == false) {

} else {

  require('xeroconfig.php');

  $XeroOAuth = new XeroOAuth(array_merge(array(
    'application_type' => XRO_APP_TYPE,
    'oauth_callback' => OAUTH_CALLBACK,
    'user_agent' => $useragent
  ), $signatures));


  $initialCheck = $XeroOAuth->diagnostics();
  $checkErrors = count($initialCheck);
  if ($checkErrors > 0) {
    // you could handle any config errors here, or keep on truckin if you like to live dangerously
    foreach ($initialCheck as $check) {
      echo 'Error: ' . $check . PHP_EOL;
    }
  } else {
    $session = persistSession(array(
        'oauth_token' => $XeroOAuth->config ['consumer_key'],
        'oauth_token_secret' => $XeroOAuth->config ['shared_secret'],
        'oauth_session_handle' => ''
    ));
    $oauthSession = retrieveSession();

    if (isset($oauthSession ['oauth_token'])) {
      $XeroOAuth->config ['access_token'] = $oauthSession ['oauth_token'];
      $XeroOAuth->config ['access_token_secret'] = $oauthSession ['oauth_token_secret'];
      $invoice_counter = 0;

      foreach ($rs as $row) {
        if(++$invoice_counter % 50 === 1) {
          $xml = "<Invoices>\n";
        }

        $xml .= "<Invoice>\n";
        $xml .= "<Type>ACCREC</Type>\n";
        $xml .= "<Contact>\n";
        $xml .= "<Name>" . xmlEscape($row['customername']) . "</Name>\n";
        $xml .= "</Contact>\n";
        $xml .= "<Date>" . xmlEscape($row['txndate']) . "</Date>\n";
        $xml .= "<DueDate>" . xmlEscape($row['Duedate']) . "</DueDate>\n";
        $xml .= "</Invoice>\n";

        if($invoice_counter % 50 === 0 || $invoice_counter == count($rs)) {
          $xml .= "</Invoices>\n";
          #echo $xml;

          $response = $XeroOAuth->request('POST', $XeroOAuth->url('Invoices', 'core'), array(), $xml);

          if ($XeroOAuth->response['code'] == 200) {
            $invoice = $XeroOAuth->parseResponse($XeroOAuth->response['response'], $XeroOAuth->response['format']);
            echo "" . count($invoice->invoices[0]) . " invoice created/updated in this Xero organisation.";
            if (count($invoice->Invoices[0]) > 0) {
              echo "The first one is: </br>";
              pr($Invoice->Invoices[0]->Invoice);
            }
          } else {
            outputError($XeroOAuth);
          }          
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```